# How do I run Python scripts on a web host that doesn't support command line access?

Tags: python, web

I have a webhost that doesn't allow command line access and yet they say you can run python scripts....how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're probably talking about [CGI scripts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) - what you need to do is write a Python script that generates HTML output and place it in the appropriate directory (usually `cgi-bin` or some such). Then navigate to this URL and you'll see the output.

This is often used for form processing, but you can do almost anything with it. [Here](http://www.penzilla.net/tutorials/python/cgi/) is a short tutorial.

Good luck!